# Once bitten twice shy

Tags: etymology, idioms, idiom-meaning

What is the meaning and origin of the idiom 'once bitten twice shy'?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/once_bitten,_twice_shy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As below,

> "William Caxton, the first English printer, gave the earliest version
>   of this saying in 'Aesope' , his translation of Aesop's fables: 'He
>   that hath ben ones begyled by somme other ought to kepe hym wel fro(m)
>   the same.'

The history:

> Centuries later, the English novelist Robert Surtees referred to the
>   saying in 'Mr. Sponge's Sporting Tour' with '(He) had been bit once,
>   and he was not going to give Mr. Sponge a second chance.' The exact
>   wording of the saying was recorded later that century in 'Folk Phrases
>   of Four Counties' by G.G. Northall and was repeated by, among others,
>   the English novelist Joseph Conrad (1920, 'The Rescue'), the novelist
>   Aldous Huxley (1928, 'Point Counter Point'), and the novelist Wyndham
>   Lewis (1930, 'The Apes of God'). 'Once bitten, twice shy' has been a
>   familiar saying in the twentieth century." From "Wise Words and Wives'
>   Tales" by Stuart Flexner and Doris Flexner (Avon Books, New York,
>   1993).
>
> A variation, "once burned, twice shy," is also traced back to "Mr.
>   Sponge's Sporting Tour." "Once burned" was "First attested in the
>   United States in 'Dead Sure' by S. Sterling." The meaning of the
>   saying is "One who had an unpleasant experience is especially
>   cautious." From the "Random House Dictionary of Popular Proverbs and
>   Sayings" by Gregory Y. Titelman (Random House, New York, 1996).
>   -http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/10/messages/453.html

Comment: In the UK "won't get burnt twice" or 'won't get burnt again " are common in usage.

Comment: Which might be related to The Who song "Won't Get Fooled Again". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Won%27t_Get_Fooled_Again

Answer (score 2):

once bitten twice shy- when something or someone has hurt you once, you tend to avoid that thing or person.

it is something that you say which means when you have had an unpleasant experience you are much more careful to avoid similar experiences in the future

idioms.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=Once+bitten%2C+twice+shy

The Internet consensus is that the phrase traces back to an English printer (William Caxton), the first to publish a translation in to English of Aesop's tales -- in 1484.

The moral of one of Aesop's stories was translated by Caxton as "He that hath ben ones begyled by somme other ought to kepe hym wel fro(m) the same". That has been rephrased and rephrased over the years, until early into the 20th century when it evolved into the tidy current phrasing.

The fable itself is about a wolf who threatens to eat a dog. The dog says "Not now, wait until after I have been fed and am fatter". Dumb wolf lets dog go. When wolf returns he can't get at the dog to eat the dog, and the dog says something along the lines of "Don't be so stupid again". Modern Moral: "Once bitten twice shy", although Caxton's "He that has been fooled once by another ought to keep away from that same person in the future" makes more sense in context of the original story.